# Can a man marry a woman with the same name as his mother? (Or vice-versa?) How?

Tags: halacha, minhag, names, marriage, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Rabbi Yehudah Hechassid wrote in his testament (Testament of R. Yehudah Hechassid, sec. 23) that a man should not marry a woman whose name is the same as his mother’s, and a woman should not marry a man whose name is the same as her father’s. Some authorities say that this testament was only intended for Rabbi Yehudah Hechassid’s own descendants, and others argue that this is good advice for everyone (Piskei Dinim Tzemach Tzedek, Yoreh De’ah 116).  How do people hold these days?  Is a common name with a parent a deal-breaker, or is there a way around it, such as a name-change?

Comment: ...or is everything ok even without a name-change?

Comment: See [this article](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/ask-the-rabbi/q-a-sharing-a-name/2004/09/08/) by Rabbi Yaakov Klass.

Answer (score 6):

Rabbi JD Bleich is strongly opposed to the name-change business, it can create bona-fide halachic problems. Suppose Shprintza wants to get married, but her mother-in-law-elect is also named Shprintza. So we go through a name-change ceremony, she's not "Shprintza" anymore, she's "Gendendel." Great. A few months or years later, people feel they've fulfilled their religious obligation and everyone starts calling her Shprintza again. If G-d forbid she'd ever need a Get, this becomes quite messy.

Basically, in some Hassidic communities it's taken seriously; in Modern Orthodox circles it's ignored; for Litvish Yeshivish it probably depends on your circles. Someone asked Rabbi Moshe Feinstein about it -- "may I marry so-and-so, but what about her mother's name..." Rabbi Feinstein replied -- stuff like this, if it seriously bothers you, then you have to keep it; otherwise, you don't. If you're writing to me for a *heter*, that proves it doesn't seriously bother you, so go for it!

Comment: Any citation for the Rabbi Bleich opposition or the _Rav Moshe_ story?

Comment: @msh210 Citation for R' Moshe's opinion: Igros Moshe EH vol. 1, § 4.

Comment: @msh210 Rabbi Bleich's opinion is mentioned [here](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/17666406/Eishus-chaburah-I-by-Harav-JD-Bleich-shlita-esq): "Rav Bleich suggests that we should be very hesitant to add new times at any time. For, after the ksubah is written, and they give the Chasan an aliyah... he will say his name is Avraham ben pluni, and not Avraham Mordechai ben pluni. Also, it is questionable if the ksubah is good.... Even if they do call him Avraham Mordechai, what are you going to write on the get?... Therefore, why create problems when you really don’t have to?"

Comment: @Shalom:  The Bleich article, Fred offers, suggests that a couple in this situation can simply go by nicknames (which they must use consistently).  I understand that Rabbi Hillel Klavan's rebbetzin had to go by a nickname for that purpose to avoid confusion with her mother-in-law.

Comment: @Fred:  I don't understand how a renaming creates problems for a get.  The sofer routinely writes every name, English, Hebrew or otherwise, that the husband and wife has ever been known by.  If someone was known as "Batman" to his friends, that name would be transliterated into Hebrew and listed in the get as an alternate name which would fully identify the person.

Comment: @BruceJames I think the point was that adding names introduces confusion and increases the likelihood that something will be recorded incorrectly or incompletely. Here's part of the quote that I earlier replaced with ellipses (I didn't include it before due to SE's character limit on comments): "Even if they do call him Avraham Mordechai, what are you going to write on the get? This causes a major headache for mesadray gittin." Anyway, I think the stuff I quoted was from a talmid's notes, but you can probably hear R' Bleich discuss this directly on YUTorah.org.

Comment: @BruceJames Having known Rabbi Klaven for many years, that's a very interesting point I never knew. Perhaps I will ask him (or his rebbetzin) about it next time I see them! Thanks!

Comment: I personally know of such a case in which Rabbi Kanievsky was consulted and he ruled that the kallah should change her name (and she did). But it seems to be on a case-by-case basis. Knowing her father, a pretty famous rav himself, he probably asked Rabbi Kanievsky because he expected him to call off the engagement.